# Determining and preventing Android Scheduling delay

Tags: android, performance, systrace

I am currently trying to improve the fluidity of my app's animation.

I ran Android systrace and found several scheduling delay alerts which according to systrace contributes to jank.

Unfortunately I am unable to comprehend the other data presented by systrace. Can someone point me in the right direction as to how to find the cause of the scheduling delays?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I've ran into the same problem. Have you found a solution to this yet?

Answer (score 10):

I found this blog post that might help you out:

> A Scheduling delay means that the thread, processing that specific
>   slice, was not scheduled on the CPU for a long time. Therefore, it
>   took longer for this thread to complete.

source: http://blog.udinic.com/2015/09/15/speed-up-your-app